# stars::read_stars and raster::raster have different projections when reading the same .nc file

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-raster, ncdf4, r-stars

I'm trying to read a `.nc` raster file in R. The older function `raster::raster()` reads the data perfectly fine. I'd like to reproduce the results using a newer function `stars::read_stars()`, but somehow it does not work for me. The data `CHAP_PM2.5_Y1K_2020_V4.nc` can be downloaded from [here](https://zenodo.org/record/6398971) (~6.1 MB). Below is a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(stars)
library(raster)

pm_raster = raster::raster('CHAP_PM2.5_Y1K_2020_V4.nc')
pm_stars = stars::read_stars('CHAP_PM2.5_Y1K_2020_V4.nc')
# Warning messages:
# 1: In CPL_read_gdal(as.character(x), as.character(options), as.character(driver),  :
#   GDAL Message 1: The dataset has several variables that could be identified as vector fields, 
# but not all share the same primary dimension. Consequently they will be ignored.
# 2: In CPL_read_gdal(as.character(x), as.character(options), as.character(driver),  :
#  GDAL Message 1: The dataset has several variables that could be identified as vector fields, 
# but not all share the same primary dimension. Consequently they will be ignored.
```

The reading the files looks good, but the problem is when I plot them, the figure read by `stars::read_stars` looks wrong:

```
plot(pm_raster, main = 'raster::raster')
plot(pm_stars, main = 'stars::read_stars')
```

It looks like the projection is wrong for `stars::read_stars()`, but I have no clue on this. Any suggestion or comment would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: as a preliminary, how does `plot(terra::flip(pm_stars), main='stars::read_stars flip')`look to you?

Comment: @Chris Thanks Chris. It produces an error: `Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': unable to find an inherited method for function ‘flip’ for signature ‘"stars"’`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I get the same.I'm going to put a 'non-answer' so that I can share some plots.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-answer but using slightly different read options. It looks like stars::read_ncdf is your better read option.

```
library(terra)
library(stars)
pm_terra <- rast('~/Downloads/CHAP_PM2.5_Y1K_2020_V4.nc')
pm_terra
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 3571, 6148, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.009999999, 0.01  (x, y)
extent      : 73.45216, 134.9322, 17.9697, 53.67971  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source      : CHAP_PM2.5_Y1K_2020_V4.nc 
varname     : PM2.5 
name        : PM2.5 
unit        : µg/m3 
plot(flip(pm_terra))

# and then using stars::read_ncdf
pm_stars_ncdf <- read_ncdf('~/Downloads/CHAP_PM2.5_Y1K_2020_V4.nc')
no 'var' specified, using PM2.5
other available variables:
 lat, lon
Will return stars object with 21954508 cells.
Warning message:
In .get_nc_projection(meta$attribute, rep_var, cv) :
  No projection information found in nc file.
```

[image: pm_using_flip_terra]

flip(terra) above

[image: pm_using_stars::read_ncdf]

stars::read_ncdf above.